# Definition of ontology

Tags: meaning

Does ontology refer to the study of being or the study of the nature surrounding being? I found conflicting definitions.

nature:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ontology

direct:

http://www.reference.com/example-sentences/ontology
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ontology

Comment: Maybe add the conflicting texts? Note that there is the metaphysical version and the computer science version

Comment: All four seen to define *ontology* as the study of the nature of being.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to turn on OP's misunderstanding of the word "nature" as used in some definitions of "ontology". It's nothing to do with *"Nature" as the "environment" within which sentient beings exist* - it simply means  "character, quality".

Comment: Someone has voted to reopen this question but I'm voting to leave it closed as it's of no value to our site, since the underlying issue is the OP's misunderstanding of a different word (*nature*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the study of the concept of existence, and the categorization of things that exist (and perhaps that don't exist).

Wikipedia lists [some fundamental questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology#Some_fundamental_questions) that ontologists consider:

- "What can be said to exist?"
- "Into what categories, if any, can we sort existing things?"
- "What are the meanings of being?"
- "What are the various modes of being of entities?"

When people talk about ontology in computer science, they tend to refer to the second part of the definition - the classification of things that exist.

When people talk about "an ontology", they refer to a particular system of classification. The term "ontology" is used in this sense in discussions related to the Semantic Web.